# How Can I send_keys to this search input field. Getting TimeOut Exception

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, timeoutexception

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\rana\OneDrive - \Desktop\auto\new.py", line 49, in <module>
    search_input = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input')))
  File "C:\Users\rana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x006137C3+48947]
        (No symbol) [0x005A8551]
        (No symbol) [0x004AC92D]
        (No symbol) [0x004D9E38]
        (No symbol) [0x004D9EFB]
        (No symbol) [0x00508EF2]
        (No symbol) [0x004F50D4]
        (No symbol) [0x005075DA]
        (No symbol) [0x004F4E86]
        (No symbol) [0x004D16C7]
        (No symbol) [0x004D284D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0085FDF9+2458985]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008A744F+2751423]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008A1361+2726609]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00690680+560624]
        (No symbol) [0x005B238C]
        (No symbol) [0x005AE268]
        (No symbol) [0x005AE392]
        (No symbol) [0x005A10B7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x762400C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77157B1E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77157AEE+238]
```

CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
options=options)


driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://10.225.244.12/mito/webpage/mito/home#no-back-button')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'details-button'))).click()
driver.find_element(By.ID,'proceed-link').click()
if driver.title == "MITO":
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.modal-body')))
    js = 'return document.querySelector("div[class=modal-body]").textContent.includes("Session Expired")'
    if driver.execute_script(js):
        print('success')
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/button'))).click()
    else:
        print("session expired message not found")
    username = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'username')))
    passwd = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password')))
    loginBtn = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'btnLogin')))
    time.sleep(3)
    username.send_keys("username")
    passwd.send_keys("password")
    loginBtn.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tree > ul > li:nth-child(9)'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tree > ul > li:nth-child(14)'))).click()
  
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
 
        
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tree > ul > li:nth-child(9)')))
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tree > ul > li:nth-child(14)')))
    time.sleep(10)
    search_input = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input')))

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView().click();", search_input)
    print(f"Element  found, attempting to send keys {search_input}")
    search_input.send_keys("hello")
        
    
print("End of script")
```

I am expecting the code to send text to search input field field . But it gives me a timeout exception. I tried multiple times but still not working.I searched by using CSS_SELECTOR, XPATH,TAGNAME.I find it strange that when i move to the page where that input field is console return null when i tried to find the element on console:
Before clicking on the input field using select element of browser
[image]
But after inspecting the element manually and clicking on it, the browser console gives the exact element.
After clicking on the input field using select element  of browser :
[image]
[image]

Comment: Clearly selenium is not able to locate the desired element. Check for presence of `IFRAME` or `shadow-root` elements which are wrapping the desired element. Also, use relative XPATH rather than absolute XPATH.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, there was an iframe present. I didn't know about that.